# How to subclass Python list without a returned empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass

I have this code

```
class lines_type(list):
    def __init__(self, lines):
        self.lines = lines[:]
lines = lines_type([1, 2, 3])
print(lines)
print(lines.lines)
```

And my output was

```
[]
[1, 2, 3]
```

But my expected output is something like this

```
<__main__.lines_type object at 0x00EC6410>
[1, 2, 3]
```

I think that `__init__` method of class list returns an empty list. So how do I extend my class from list but not receive an empty list?

Comment: You're mixing up inheritance and composition. If your class inherits from `list`, `self` *is* a list. You don't need to stick another list onto it as an attribute.

Comment: @user2357112, Thanks for your reply. But can I stick another list onto an attribute and self is not a list?

Comment: If you don't want `self` to be a list, don't inherit from `list`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one problem here is that you didn't `__init__` the list in the subclass' `__init__` - so do this:

```
class lines_type(list):
    def __init__(self, lines):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.lines = lines[:]
```

However, if you don't want "self" to be a list, then do not subclass from list.

```
class lines_type(object):
    def __init__(self, lines):
        self.lines = lines[:]
```

which, when printing `lines` and `lines.lines` in your example, should output

```
<__main__.lines_type object at 0x...>
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @GrakT No problem :D